# Reading PHP_VALUE from within php script using init_get() on Nginx server always returning php.ini default

Tags: nginx, overriding, php

I know, this is not a question directly relating to a programming issue, but i understand it to match the rule **software tools commonly used by programmers**, since my development environment depends on this working piece of software. I couldn't find any helpful information in the Nginx Wiki in the Nginx Forum, so my hope was to find the answer at this professional platform. And since there are many other Nginx related questions to find here, i thought, this might not be an off topic question.
I'm coming from an Apache-background and am trying to migrate my server to Nginx. In the configuration file of my site i defined some fastcgi values to override the php.ini file, which i wanna leave untouched, like so:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "post_max_size = 15M";
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 5M";
```

There are a couple more. Now i wonder, how i can get hand on 'em from within my PHP script. As  with Apache using ini_get() does not work, or return the php.ini default value. I searched the Nginx docs and the web for an answer, but can't find one.

Somebody would tell me, how to achive this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to declare multiple php_value's on nginx, you should combine the values inside a single `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE` directive like below. otherwise, only the last one is passed to php-fpm process.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    [...]
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "
        post_max_size=15M
        upload_max_filesize=5M
        ";
    [...]
}
```

i believe this is why you see the default value or the value set in php.ini, if you tried `ini_get("post_max_size")`.